# Programmatically get typed syntax tree from facebook's flow type-inferencer

Tags: javascript, flowtype, type-inference

How can I programmatically use  flow (facebook's type-inferencer for javascript) and obtain the typed syntax tree in ocaml? Where is a good entry point?